# Non-Jew who takes a Jewish name

Tags: halacha, gentiles, names

Let's say someone goes through an invalid conversion, and now they incorrectly think they are Jewish.  They pick a Jewish name for themselves, and they are called up to the Torah by that name and use it for whenever else the situation arises that it would be relevant to them.

If they get sick, and you wanted to daven for them or say a Mi Sheberach for them, could you / should you use the name they "picked" for themselves?

My question is not because of the Jewishness of the name.  My question is because it is a) not their given name, or the name they go by regularly and b) taken under false pretenses.

Comment: Perhaps there is an issue of appearing to validate the conversion? Then again, if you used their father's name (as was the Lubavitcher Rebbe's practice for all non-Jews that asked him for a blessing) then that may be enough of a distinction in any event.

Comment: Two of my neighborhood rabbis told me that there i sno problem included non-Jews among the names in the "mi sheberach" list, and of course, I use their non-Jeiwsh names. Granted that what you mentioned is a bit different, but I would deduce that it may not matter which name you use for Mi Sheberach, anyway.

Comment: The din is that a ger in a get can in some circumstances use his non Jewish name. A meshumad though cannot because this would 'validate' his becoming a meshumad. A misheberach to my mind is no different.

Comment: @preferred This person is like a ger or a meshumad?  They aren't either.

Comment: @YEZ Even if a meshumad was given a new 'Jewish' name it is still not used. TAZ 129:7 A reform could be called a meshumad.

Comment: @preferred You misunderstood the question.  He's not reform - he's a gentile.  His conversion is invalid.

Comment: @YEZ but if he underwent now a real conversion would he be given a new name or keep the reform one.

Comment: @preferred I suppose that would be up to him, but what does it have to do with this?

Comment: @YEZ If an orthodox bais din would ask for a new name that would answer your question.

Comment: @preferred Orthodox bais din definitely does not make them choose a new name - I know several people who went through this process.  But even if they did, I'm not sure if that would show whether his name had validity as a goy.  Beis din's desire to not validate the other conversion once he does a legitimate one doesn't indicate what would be if they had no such need because he didn't do a new conversion.